# Halftone Image effect

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code to recieve an image and turn this to B&W:

```
public Bitmap GrayScaleFilter(Bitmap image)
    {
        Bitmap grayScale = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

        for (Int32 y = 0; y < grayScale.Height; y++)
            for (Int32 x = 0; x < grayScale.Width; x++)
            {
                Color c = image.GetPixel(x, y);

                Int32 gs = (Int32)(c.R * 0.3 + c.G * 0.59 + c.B * 0.11);

                grayScale.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(gs, gs, gs));
            }
        return grayScale;
    }
```

Now, i need to do a new method to do a Halftone effect with this b&w image.
I know that this effect is based on this http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/CG/Aulas/Img/IMG.htm

But now, how to use this to turn my image into Halftone?

Comment: @CharlieSalts Pretty sure the Homework tag was deprecated a while back.

Comment: The page you linked contains the answer.Use floyd steinberg dithering or search for an implementation of this (simple) algorithm

Comment: @Lucas Grubba: Be sure to visit http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions if this indeed a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept of halftone is the mapping of a pixel intensity to the size of the target circle. One possibility is the following math:

```
double sum = 1.0 - (pixel / 255.0)
double size = sum * SQUARE_ROOT_2;
```

With this size you can draw your circle like this:

```
int maxdotsize = 10;
ellipse(x, y, 
    (size * maxdotsize), 
    (size * maxdotsize));
```

I implemented this algorithm in Java for Processing. Look [here](https://github.com/Milchreis/processing-imageprocessing/blob/4d31cda93c48daf07f0f0d2f72e0b287d02266fe/src/milchreis/imageprocessing/Halftone.java#L62) for the complete code.